# xml разметка в android

Tags: android, xml

почему не отображается Switch элемент

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Settings"/>

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Dark mode"/>

            </LinearLayout>



        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Вот весь код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="66dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:overlay="true"

    >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".First_Layout.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/translate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

                android:id="@+id/wordEnglishMainActivity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Find"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/Find"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="Find"
                android:text="Translate Word" />

            <RadioGroup

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/first"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Red"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Blue"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/trid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Green"/>
            </RadioGroup>

        </RelativeLayout>






    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>



        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Settings"/>

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial

                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Dark mode"/>

            </LinearLayout>



        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>








</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Он отоброжается просто за пределами видимости. У вас LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией, в нем кнопка с шириной match_parent. В итоге кнопка имеет ширину лайаута, а свитч помещается справа от нее, уже за пределами лайаута. Сделайте, например, так

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Settings"/>

                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Dark mode"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое